# Properly arranging items in the collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I wonder how to separate the REST API address for downloading data about the movie. Currently, my assumptions are to give a separate address for each type of information.

```
/api/v1.0/movies/contributions/othertitles/{id}
/api/v1.0/movies/contributions/boxoffice/{id}
/api/v1.0/movies/contributions/releasedates/{id}
e.g.
```

This controller only accepts the contribution ID

```
@GetMapping(value = "/contributions/othertitles/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public
Contribution<OtherTitle> getOtherTitleContribution(
        @PathVariable final Long id
) {
    return this.contributionSearchService.getOtherTitleContribution(id);
}
```

However, I thought to make the controller more universal.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/contributions/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public
Contribution<? extends MovieRequest> getContribution(
        @PathVariable final Long id,
        @PathVariable final MovieField field
) {
    return this.contributionSearchService.getContribution(id, field);
}
```

Only then there is a problem with the service method that retrieves the contribution. For example, it looks like this.

```
    @Override
public Contribution<OtherTitle> getOtherTitleContribution(
        Long contributionId
) {
    final ContributionEntity contributionEntity = this.findContribution(contributionId);
    final Contribution<OtherTitle> contribution = contributionEntity.getDTO();

    contributionEntity.getIdsToAdd()
            .forEach(id -> {
                final MovieOtherTitle otherTitle = this.entityManager.find(MovieOtherTitle.class, id);
                contribution.getElementsToAdd().put(otherTitle.getId(), otherTitle.getDTO());
            });
    contributionEntity.getIdsToUpdate()
            .forEach((key, value) -> {
                final MovieOtherTitle otherTitleToUpdate = this.entityManager.find(MovieOtherTitle.class, key);
                final MovieOtherTitle otherTitleUpdated = this.entityManager.find(MovieOtherTitle.class, value);
                contribution.getElementsToUpdate().put(otherTitleToUpdate.getId(), otherTitleToUpdate.getDTO());
                contribution.getElementsUpdated().put(otherTitleToUpdate.getId(), otherTitleUpdated.getDTO());
            });
    contributionEntity.getIdsToDelete()
            .forEach(id -> {
                final MovieOtherTitle otherTitle = this.entityManager.find(MovieOtherTitle.class, id);
                contribution.getElementsToDelete().put(otherTitle.getId(), otherTitle.getDTO());
            });

    return contribution;
}
```

If I would like to pass this object from the controller to the site and operate on it what information I want to download, it would be a lot of problems.

It seems to me that the most optimal is to leave it as it is now and just split into several addresses and several methods in the service. What do you think?

Comment: me again :) .  Why do you have your DTO in your entity?

Comment: This method converts basic data to DTO. https://pastebin.com/XChmXCex

Comment: ok.  by "the site" you mean the front end application i guess ? why do you think you'll have problems when you'll have to manipulate your data in the front end application ? btw you url would be better with a more restful schema /contributions/{idcontrib}/nestedContributionStruct

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Each information has an entity. Creating one method that manipulates classes will be a nice brothel. 3. You mean separating addresses into /api/v1.0/movies/contributions/{id}/othertitles  e.g.

Comment: 2. it is the best solution i guess (at least for now). This will be simpler and easier to debug and scale if needed. By trying to generify everything you will be over designing your application a make it harder to understand to newcomers. Make It Work, Make It Right, Make It Fast. 3. Yes. Read the restful apis URI definition .